# efficient combination of strings

Tags: python, optimization

I have to find a way of splitting long string into shorter ones that gives the most points. Some combinations have assigned values, like 'tr'=1 'er'=3 'tre'=2. All letters that I don't use are worth -1 point each. So for example with string 'trer' my program has to choose 'tr-er'=4 instead of 'tre-r'=1. I can't find any algorithm that can find all the ways of splitting I have to test. I used regular expressions to list every combination with value, but don't know what to do next.

Comment: You say you don't know how to find all the ways of splitting. But then you say that you have already listed every combination. So which one is it?

Comment: `itertools.combinations` applied to the list of potential split indices is the way to go, though if the original string is long such brute force might be prohibitive.

Comment: Kevin I didn't say it clearly. I have listed every substring that has assigned value in long string, but struggle finding ways that these substings combined make whole string. I'll try itertool it seems to be just what I was looking for. :)